# Batch search and replace in file removes the character "!"

Tags: batch-file

Currently I'm trying to create a batch script that's suppose to automatically create files for a back end in C#. The batch script takes inputs as variables and creates various of files from previously written templates and modifies existing ones.

However the "Startup.cs" file includes a "!" character that disappears when being modified.

In this step I'm modifying the "Startup.cs" file to add a singleton to the services.

I've tried the batch script on other computers and on files with other special characters than "!", which seems to work.

```
:addService
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /in "services.AddSingleton" .\PATH_TO_STARTUP.CS_FILE\Startup.cs') do SET /a found=%%a
SET /a line=found+1
SET "file=.\PATH_TO_STARTUP.CS_FILE\Startup.cs"
SET "newFile=Startup.cs"
(
  For /f "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A in (
    'Findstr /N ".*" "%file%"'
  ) Do IF %%A Equ %line% (
      ECHO             services.AddSingleton^<I%serviceName%Service, %serviceName%Service^>^(^);
      ECHO        }
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO:%%B
  )
) >"%newFile%"

XCOPY /y Startup.cs .\PATH_TO_STARTUP.CS_FILE\ >NUL
DEL Startup.cs >NUL
ENDLOCAL
FOR %%A IN (.\PATH_TO_STARTUP.CS_FILE\Startup.cs) DO SET "size=%%~zA"
ECHO [34mUPDATE[0m .\PATH_TO_STARTUP.CS_FILE\Startup.cs ^(%size% bytes^)
GOTO:EOF
```

I expected to file to be an exact copy of the previous "Startup.cs" file, but with the created service as a line below the other services in the file. This is currently working, however the "Startup.cs" file has the line:

```
if (cs != null)
```

Which is being modified to this:

```
if (cs = null)
```

So the character "!" is being removed during the adding of the service.

Comment: nowhere in the posted code you ***do*** use delayedexpansion, so why do you enable it (the cause for the vanished `!`)?

Comment: @LotPings That was it. Thanks a lot! :)